# Compare the data in two tables, one is Oracle, the other is SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have two databases, one is Oracle 11g and the other is in Sql Server 2012.  There is a table in the Oracle database that contains a column called BASE_ID.  This is comprised of work order numbers.

In the Sql Server database, there is also a table that contains a column called WorkOrders.  This also contains work order numbers.  What I need to do is compare what is in the Oracle column to what is in the SQL Server column, and display what is in Oracle but not in Sql Server.  I am a little stumped here, even for a starting point.  I am kind of just taking pot shots.  This mess is what I have so far:

```
   private void compare()
    {
        try
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Open();
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            OracleCommand oraCmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT BASE_ID FROM WORK_ORDER x WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM [SQLServer].[BACRTest].[WorkOrders] y WHERE y.WorkOrder = x.BASE_ID)", oraconn);
            OracleDataAdapter dt = new OracleDataAdapter(oraCmd);
            dt.Fill(t);
            dataGridView3.DataSource = t;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

This is just throwing me an `ORA-00903: invalid table name` error which is fair enough because I wasn't really expecting it to work.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why not fetch date from both db respectively and then compare in memory?

Comment: I thought of something like this.  Fetch the data into a variable and compare.  I am just not too sure how to go about it.

Comment: Is there a connection between the Oracle and SQL Server databases which allows Oracle to query the SQL Server tables or vice versa? You may need to discuss this with your DBAs.

Answer (score 2):

As noted above, if you have the correct products installed (e.g. Oracle's Database Gateway for SQL Server, or Database Gateway for ODBC) you can make a direct connection between Oracle and SQL Server. If you don't have such products you can try exporting the SQL Server table to a comma-separated values (.csv) file, then set up an external table in Oracle to read the .csv. Not perhaps the most seamless method in the world, but it does represent one way to handle this.

Best of luck.

Comment: I second Bob's suggestion - import one of the tables into the other database and compare the two tables there. Comparing them by pulling the data from both and doing the comparison in C#, Java or bash (or Excel or whatever) will be much messier by comparison, especially if you have a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

Because the entries are on different DBMSs, you cannot directly make a query for this, so most likely you will need to store the entries in memory and compare them one by one. Maybe you could partition the tables into small sets and compare them

Comment: If you have the correct products (e.g. Oracle's Database Gateway for SQL Server, or Database Gateway for ODBC if the Oracle instance is running on a platform which supports ODBC) you can certainly do this; however, it does require a bit of work to set up.